# I create a file called "foo-bar.service" and it becomes "foo-bar.service.app"

Tags: file-extensions

File browser windows show this .app extension, but if I go into the terminal it's just "foo-bar.service"

How can I get rid of this annoying, obnoxious nonsense?

Comment: A quick test (`touch test.service`) shows that any file created with the `.service` file extension is named `.service.app` in the Finder. Why that should be, I don't know, though `.service.app` files can be found in `/System/Library/Services`. However, user-created MacOS Services usually have the extension `.workflow`. What sort of file are you trying to create?

Comment: @benwiggy The file is a systemctl config file for a different computer running ubuntu...  The point is, Apple is, as usual, annoying-- my OS should not be magically altering file names that I create just because its name happens to match ".service"

Comment: If the filename isn't actually changed in the Terminal, and only in the Finder, does it matter for Ubuntu?

Comment: No, it's just more unexpected and bizarre behavior that I would rather my computer not do.  I would just prefer my OS to not obfuscate and perform magical nonsense on my files...